# Why does returning arr.includes() is different than returning true in a conditionnal statement verifying the same array?

Tags: javascript, return, include, conditional-statements

I am building a 'search engine' so that my client can access some documents based on their categories and ids. To do so, I filter all the available documents so I only display those that match the current page (it can be a news page, financial page, event page, etc.)

I ran into a bug and, luckily, discovered that there was a difference that I still don't understand...

**CASE 1**
Gives me 113 results

```
const allDocuments = [{id: 1, ....}, {id: 2, ....}, {id: 3, ...}, ...]
const currentPageIds = [1, 2, 3]

const filteredDocuments = allDocuments.filter(document => {
          // each document have one or more category ids
          for(const categoryID of document.category_id) {
            return currentPageIds.includes(categoryID)
        }
      })
```

**CASE 2**
Gives me 134 results

```
const allDocuments = [{id: 1, ....}, {id: 2, ....}, {id: 3, ...}, ...]
const currentPageIds = [1, 2, 3]

const filteredDocuments = allDocuments.filter(document => {
          // each document have one or more category ids
          for(const categoryID of document.category_id) {
            if(currentPageIds.includes(categoryID)) {
              return true
            }
         }
      })
```

As I understand it, the function `includes()` is supposed to return a bolean value, so in my example how is it  different from returning true inside a conditional statement ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please add some data with `category_id` in it.

Comment: Your first snippet immediately `return`s from the first iteration of the `for(const categoryID of document.category_id) {`, only checking whether the first category is included in the `currentPageIds` and disregarding the other categories.

Comment: @NinaScholz the data doesn't matter here as my question is regarding the expected behaviour of returning the function includes() directly or using a conditional statement and then returning true

Comment: the first on loops only once. for each `document`.

Comment: @Bergi ohh my god...such a noob mistake I made. I don't know how I missed this! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic of case 1, you are returning false there for cases where you should return true, and this explains why case 1 finds less cases

See comments in the next code for extra explanation

```
const filteredDocuments = allDocuments.filter(document => {
          // each document have one or more category ids
          for(const categoryID of document.category_id) {
            // here sometimes you are returning false, when you should be returning true
            // this happens here for example when the first category 
 // in document.category_id is not included in currentPageIds, while next pages in document.category_id may be included
            return currentPageIds.includes(categoryID)
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If we convert your Case 1, into direction of your Case 2. It will be following code. In your Case 2. the else block is missing. That maybe the reason for difference results.

```
for (const categoryID of document.category_id) {
  if (currentPageIds.includes(categoryID)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you try with

```
const filteredDocuments = allDocuments.filter((doc) =>
  doc?.category_id?.some((id) => currentPageIds.includes(id))
);
```

Hope this helps.